# Findcontours() run-time error

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, runtime-error

I am using a function like this;

```
Mat large = imread(path+name);
Mat rgb;
if (large.rows > 2500 || large.cols > 1250)
{
    pyrDown(large, rgb);
}
else
{
    rgb = large.clone();
}
cv::Mat smallx;
cvtColor(rgb, smallx, CV_BGR2GRAY);
Mat grad,connected,bw;

Mat morphKernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
cv::morphologyEx(smallx, grad, MORPH_GRADIENT, morphKernel);
cv::threshold(grad, bw, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY + THRESH_OTSU);
morphKernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(9, 1));
cv::morphologyEx(bw, connected, MORPH_CLOSE, morphKernel);

Mat mask = Mat::zeros(bw.size(), CV_8UC1);
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

cv::findContours(connected, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
```

Some input images prompt exception when function returns, it throws me to "_Mybase::deallocate(_Ptr, _Count);" code block in xmemory0 class. I must catch this kind of errors and prevent this process from unexpected suspensions

--------------ERROR DETAILS--------------

I tried that code block with 30 different input but it gave error in a few image. after findcontours it thrown an exception break and show me this message.

> Unhandled exception at 0x74477fb2 (ucrtbase.dll) in
>   ImageRecognizer.exe: 0xC0000409: 0xc0000409.

in that time , "vector" class opening in my Visual Studio with these lines ;

```
~vector() _NOEXCEPT
    {   // destroy the object
    _Tidy();
    }
```

or "xmemory" class opening with these lines;

```
void deallocate(pointer _Ptr, size_type _Count)
    {   // deallocate object at _Ptr, ignore size
    _Mybase::deallocate(_Ptr, _Count);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that number of counters your method finds exceeds 50000.
Try not to use magic numbers. It is always a bad practice.

Comment: well, I've tried to initialize vectors without 50000 but in that time it I get same error for more inputs. Anyway I know that it is not useful solution but I must solve this error completely.

Comment: try to run without Point(0,0)
and try this overloaded method 
void cv::findContours(InputOutputArray  image, OutputArrayOfArrays  contours, int mode, int method, Point offset = Point())

Comment: I can try without point but I need hierarchy. I've already know this method option but it is not useful for my case. But I am going to test without Point(0,0).

Comment: did you try to visualize images "connected"? Could you please attach the  picture of the image, where exception happens?  Maybe there were no contours found?

Comment: You may want to test my code block with this images [image1](http://imgur.com/a/yAClR)
[image2](http://imgur.com/a/yAClR)

Comment: I run your code on the yellow picture with text and it run successfully.

Comment: Which version of opencv you are  using ? I am trying with 2.4.12 may be it is about my opencv configurations ?

Comment: 3.2 try to reinstall opencv (it is very simple for windows, because they provide installer)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to OpenCV 2.4.13 instead of OpenCV 2.4.12 and problem solved by itself. It wasn't an algorithm or logical error. It was a library bug.